# Where is 'Move to changelist' option in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

The official docs [says](https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-changelists.html) :

> Select one or more files and use Context Menu → Move to changelist to
>   add an item to a changelist.

But when I right-click on a file, and select TortoiseSVN, I get the following :

[image]

How do I add files to the change list ?

***Edit :*** As per Aloc's answer (and comments), files can be added to a change list from the the 'Commit' dialog. Here's my commit dialog, but I can't find any option to add a file to any change list.

[image]

**I am most interested in adding files to the `ignore-on-commit` changelist**, which is described in the same doc as

```
TortoiseSVN reserves one changelist name for its own use, namely ignore-on-commit. This is used to mark versioned files which you almost never want to commit even though they have local changes.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the documentation page you linked more carefully. This action must be taken from the `Commit` or `Check for Modifications` dialog, not directly from the Explorer context menu.

Comment: From the 'Commit' dialog, we can see the files already moved to some change list. You can't move files to checklist from there. If possible, please attach a screenshot.

Comment: @Daud what version of TortoiseSVN are you using? To move a file to a changelist within the Commit dialog, drag and drop it in the lower pane. The part that's worded poorly in the docs is that you can drag from Windows Explorer *into the Commit dialog* to put a file into a changelist.

Comment: I am using version 1.8.1. I have edited my answer to include the screenshot of what I'm getting on opening the 'Commit' dialog. My ultimate purpose is to add some files to the default *ignore-on-commit* checklit

Comment: @duad you have to right-click the file in the lower pane of the Commit dialog, and it'll be the last item in the menu.

Comment: @alroc Found it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Reviving an old thread in order to get some little extra info on the topic: I got here searching for how to add an item to the ignore-on-submit changelist directly, without passing though the commit or check for modifications dialogues. I expected some advanced changelist management UI somewhere, but as far as I can tell, if I want to add to the list an updated/non modified file, the only way is to open the check for modification dialoge for the parent folder, show all the files in it and manually look for the single items I want to add to the list. Anyone knows a smarter way to manage that?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Alroc's answer and comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41741660/443259), here's the dummy explanation of how I did it.

We need to right-click on the file, and select '`Commit`'. In the commit menu, right-click on the file again, and see the last item on the menu. Its '`Move to changelist'`

[image]